# Access totals not persistent in data export

Tags: ms-access

I'm adding sum totals to 2 particular columns in a table, currently in Datasheet View and using the Totals button. This adds the total at the bottom of the rows, problem is when I export as TXT or XLSX file, the totals aren't included.

How can I add some totals to a table so that they are still present in the exported data?

[image: table with total added at the bottom]

Comment: Access is persistent. The totals aren't table data hence not included in your export. Use a query as per this example: [Add a summary row to MS Access query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839214/add-a-summary-row-to-ms-access-query)

Comment: Why do you export the data? And can't the target application calculate the total?